# React - Route with pagenumber not working (Pagination)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, hyperlink, pagination

I try to implement pagination.
Im at my site localhost:3000/profile/ and it shows me the first 3 elements.
Also the pagination itself works fine when i use for ${page} a Number liek 3 it will go to site 3.
But what not working is my url:

localhost:3000/profile/page/2

moves me to and no more to 
and i dont know why...

```
<Route
    path='/profile'
    element={isLogged ? <Profile /> : <NotFound />}
    exact
/>
<Route
    path='/profile/:page'
    element={isLogged ? <Profile /> : <NotFound />}
    exact
/>
```

Comment: are you saying that when you go to the next page, your URL do not get change, is this the problem you are having?

Comment: The URL is changing. But it redirect me to my NotFound Page. path='/profile/:page' it should recognize this url and show me still the profile but it doesn't...

Comment: How the value of isLogged  is set? can you show the code related to that?

Comment: I edit my post with it. But i think thats not the problem. I never had a problem with this before...

Comment: Tried without login <Route path='/profile/:page' element={<Profile />} exact /> Still same. Thats 100% not the problem. most likely it's something easier a typo or mistkae with a / but I can't fine it -.-

Comment: do you remember what last change you made, like changing react router version or something else?

Comment: I didnt change someting about my Routes lately. I just worked on implementing pagination. Everything that worked before still works. Just the new /profile/:page not working. And with useParams() i wanna get the number from the URL and then show the correct data

Comment: when you refresh the page like profile/2 does it gives you the same error?

Comment: idk... the site is kinda big. If i refresh from the 404 page im getting a Network error. Cannot GET /profile/page/api/settings but this is related to data loaded in to the navbar and footer... Btw. I found that this subpage has to be nested i tried to nest it but still not working do you know if it has to be nested or not?

Comment: Nested component was the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested routes are required to make subroutes with params working

```
<Route
        path='/profile'
        element={isLogged ? <Profile /> : <NotFound />}
        exact
      >
        <Route
          path='page/:page'
          element={isLogged ? <Profile /> : <NotFound />}
          exact
        />
      </Route>
```